# Laptop Startup issue

Tags: boot, laptop, battery

So I would be using my laptop normally and then putting it to sleep. The next day I try to turn it on and it does it not work; no power button lights, no fan sounds, no screen, nothing. Note that it sits on the table so no moving or shaking takes place. So with trial and error I learned to open the back cover and unplug the battery wire and plug it in again. Then it would work instantly without even me pressing the power key.

Any suggestions what might be the issue? or how to solve it without having to unplug and re-plug the battery key?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wonder if the battery is faulty and deeply discharging and not being able to start again.  What happens if you leave the battery wire unplugged?

Comment: The laptop works fine on battery (when unplugged). Do you mean leaving it unplugged and running on AC?

Comment: @davidgo BTW thank you very much for your reply and sorry for not responding quickly. I got busy and was not able to check my msgs. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I meant running the laptop without the battery plugged in.  I still think this is worthwhile to attempt as most laptop batteries have some logic/charge management circuits inside and that could be where the issue is.

Comment: Got it.. Will test and let you know. But the thing is that this problem is very random and once I unplug the battery wire and plugging it it works fine. I guess I'll have to wait until this happens again and try that.. but thanks anyway.. ( I assume I understood you right) .. Thanks again.